# Using Virtualization Software for LAN with WCF

Tags: web-services, excel, vsto, virtual-machine

I have made an Excel VSTO Application(WPF) which call a WCF working with IIS and SQL server 2008 all installed on my PC. 
The AB look like this :

> address="http://localhost:3359/VdmService.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"

I'm now want to build a LAN Environment so that another Excel VSTO Application installed on the other Virtual Machines can communicate with this Webservice.

1. Is that a good idea? the way i want to proceede?
2. If yes, Which virtualization software should i used? of course whose can feed my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! blame on me! i found it out :

here : [Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

for my example i just change the link to : `http://10.0.2.2:3359/VdmService.svc`

I can access it through a browser on my Virtual Win7(VirtualBox).

Cheers