# Testing a client/server Java application on a virtual machine using VirtualBox

Tags: java, sockets, networking, virtualbox

I'm testing a client-server based Java application where a specific scenario involves having both the client and server running on the same host (i.e., the client connects to the server running on `localhost`). This seems to work fine except for when I test this scenario on a virtual machine (running 32bit Windows 7) using VirtualBox.

*Note: Everything henceforth is running inside the virtual machine*. I start the server and try to connect to it using the client but the connection times out. Surprisingly, I tried connecting to the server using putty and the connection behaved as expected. Both the Java client and putty tried to connect to `localhost` - the client failed but putty succeeded.

Does anyone have a possible explanation for why this might be happening?

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of [Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

Comment: Can you telnet to the service using localhost and port? Can you connect if you use the hostname instead of localhost?

Comment: I guess it is IPV4 and IPV6 issue, i would suggest try by IP than using localhost.

Comment: @thinksteep, to be more specificy, I'd say try `127.0.0.1`. This reminds me when that even didn't work on Android and one had to use some special IP to do communicate with the localhost during development.

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect to the localhost? By connecting to the hostname "localhost"? You could try connecting to the `InetAddress` returned by [getLocalHost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29)