# how to reach the computer address from android device

Tags: android, apache, http, tomcat, servlets

I have installed android development environment on VirtualBox Windows 7

There, i also installed xampp with apache tomcat

I deployed a servlet installation to the tomcat folder, accessible by http:// localhost :8080 via the browser in the virtualbox

now I want to send an http request to this servlet, however i am having connection timeout errors, which means the url that i am trying is incorrect

note that http://  10.0.2.2:8080/ didnt work and neither did http://  10.0.2.15:8080 or http://  192.168.16.1:8080 (which is the ip address ipconfig gave me)

what would be the correct address i need to send the request to ?

Comment: Could you please provide some of your code?

Comment: is the android connected to the same LAN? Did you try to deactivate your firewall?

Comment: i disabled the firewall, still didn't help, i disabled the lan as well, and that didn't help as well

Comment: This might help: [Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine).

Comment: which files do i need to edit in the xamp ?