# surf to my localhost from a virtual machine in virtual box

Tags: internet-explorer-8, localhost, virtual-machine

I'm doing some fixes for ie8 and would like to try it on a real ie8 (rather than with ietester or emulation in ie).
So I would like to remote with my vitual machine in virtual box to my local host.
Is that possible? If so, how?

(both the vm and the regular machine uses win 7)

Comment: I think your question has already been answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine?rq=1

Comment: I tried that but I didnt get it to work. I added "10.0.2.2   outer" in my hostfile on my real machine then i tried to surf to http://10.0.2.2:45608 from my vm. Nothing!