# Accessing an application on localhost from guest machine in virtual box in windows 8 and XP

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am unable to access applications running on my host machine via `localhost` on my guest machine. I have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262143/1048479), and tried to implement several answers but I am unable to access `localhost` in XP and Windows 8 (Windows 7 works fine).

My configuration on the all of the virtual boxes:

- **VirtualBox**: I have 1 network adapter, which is set to `NAT`
- **OS**: I have added `10.0.2.2 localhost` to `C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- An application running at `:4567` on my host machine is accessible in the guest machine via `http://10.0.2.2:4567` but not `http://localhost:4567`

I have several large applications interacting with the application I am currently testing that all hard code resources to `localhost`, so using anything but `localhost` is not going to work.
I understand that this is not ideal, but I don't have the time to make things more flexible at the moment :\

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a quick workaround, you only have to install an Apache HTTP server on the guest acting as a reverse proxy towards the host. The config should be something like :

```
<VirtualHost *:4567> 
# 
ServerName localhost
ProxyPass / http://10.0.2.2:4567/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.2.2:4567/
#
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You make a good point. Ideally I wouldn't want to proxy something like this, but I will go this route if there are no other options.