# Mosquitto MQTT broker on virtual machine unable to listen from other device in local network

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, mqtt, mosquitto

I have this Mosquitto MQTT broker installed on OpenSUSE on virtualbox.

However I'm not able to mosquitto_pub/ mosquitto_sub from my Raspberry Pi connected in same network.

The virtual machine is configured with bridged adapter in network setting.

I'm able to ping the VM's OpenSUSE from my Pi and the other way round.

I've tried to change the roles by install Mosquitto broker in Pi and mosquitto_pub from VM's OpenSUSE and it worked.

I've also tried to locally mosquitto_pub from VM's OpenSUSE to the local broker, and it worked.

I did not change anything from VM's OpenSUSE mosquitto.conf file, is there any configuration I need to do to make the broker in VM to listen to remote devices?

Comment: From what you've said, this sounds a problem with your VM network config, not with the mosquitto config.

Comment: What configuration would you recommend to get this work? Thanks

Comment: First thing to do would test whether this is the case or not - can you e.g. SSH from the remote machine to the VM? If not, then it is a networking problem and you would be better directing the question more towards virtual box.

Comment: I cant ssh from remote device to VM, but can do the other way round. So it's a networking problem. What to do now?

Comment: I'd close this question and open one on virtual box instead.

Comment: This is most likely a firewall on the vm, try running "sudo iptables -F"

Comment: Take a look here [Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)