# Webpack-Dev-Server Throwing Error when Accessed from VirtualBox

Tags: internet-explorer, virtual-machine, virtualbox, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to test my website compatibility for Internet Explorer 11, using VirtualBox in my Mac. I ran a local server using Webpack-Dev-Server.

When I accessed the web page via http://10.0.2.2:8080, the site is loaded fine; but the inspector panel keep throwing this error repeatedly:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd. 

[WDS] Disconnected!
```

Any clues how to fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There may be many reasons, one may be in frontend paths:

In my setup the webpack server was proxying into Symfony server at localhost:8000. At frontend, I had that path in a config variable:

```
var configuration = {
    apiPath: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
}
```

That caused requests into localhost:8000 inside VirtualBox.
I changed it to have VirtualBox localhost bridge path:

```
var configuration = {
    apiPath: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1/'
}
```

With that change I got my app working in VirtualBox.

Comment: Legend! I had my webpack config 'publicPath' set to the IIS 'http://localhost:4000', but when I access it in VirtualBox it's via a 'http://localhost.fiddler:4000' url. Updating the webpack config with the 'fiddler' url solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set localhost to 10.0.2.2 in your hosts file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723681/635134) shows how.