# Access to localhost in virtualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a server on port 8085 (my pc - I use Ubuntu 16.04). There are also Virtualbox with installed Windows 7. I have an internet connection in Windows (it is possible to open `google.com` etc) but there is no connection to localhost. For `localhost:8085` in Ubuntu everything works perfectly but for the same adress in virtual-machine doesn't work.

I tried to modify Settings->Network and put there `bridged` but there is the same problem.

How is it possible to access it?

Comment: Duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
or get ip address with terminal command ifconfig and use the address in the url

Comment: Like A-Stefani commented, one can easily access localhost using 10.0.2.2 ip. No configuration needed